# Scrapy CrawlSpider output with spaces and functions

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm currently writing a scraper with scrapy. I want to crawl all the text that is shown on the website, not a single page, but all the subpages aswell. I#m using CrawlSpider, because I think it's made for scraping the other pages aswell. Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exporters import XmlItemExporter

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'eship2'
    allowed_domains = ['tlk-energy.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.tlk-energy.com']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)] # Follow any link scrapy finds (that is allowed).

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.meta['link_text']
        item['body'] = '\n'.join(response.xpath('//text()').extract())
        return item
```

I get an output which suits my wishes very well but I still have a lot of tabs and spaces like this one:

```
> Wärmepumpen- Klimakreislauf E-Fahrzeug
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> Projektbeschreibung   
> 
> Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet
> egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia
> scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit
> amet arcu.
```

and also some text like this one:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-77796939-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I just want a file, for example xml where the text of the website is shown and maybe the url where the text was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some postprocessing to clear you results:

1. To remove javascript and css text from your results use this:

   `results = response.xpath(
      '//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()'
   ).extract()`
2. Then apply `strip` and `if` to remove empty lines:

   `text = " ".join([x.strip() for x in results if x.strip()])`

Comment: i adjusted the code you suggested, and now it works! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: one last question. now i get a text without any paragraphs, what I wanted. But is there a option to get a paragraph when there is one in the text? Then it will be easier to read the text. If not, it's okay how it is now.

Comment: That depends on how the HTML is structured. If the text you want is inside a `<p>` tag, you can use selectors to just get that specified tag and avoid getting the rest.  You will need to know some css or xpath to select only what you want from the website.